# HTML Content over flowing bootstrap containers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page with some bootstrap wells: http://jsfiddle.net/LmwbkLo6/

```
<div style="margin:15px;">
  <br>
  <div class="well">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <h4>Test Title</h4>
      <p>Some test text</p>
      <p>More text..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    </div>
    <p>And Some Text Here
      <p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Im having an issue with the content overflowing the parent containers.

For Example, the content here is overflowing the Well div. I can "fix" this by adding `class="col-xs-12"` to the Well Div, but then the div itself will overflow the outer div.

Does anyone have any Ideas?

Comment: try using class="container"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your `class="col-*` `divs` in `<div class="row"></div>` or it will not apply the negative margin.

Comment: This is correct, I have forgotten the grid system (its been a while).

Is there also a rule that all child divs will overflow their containers unless that have a class="col-*" or class="row" or class="container", etc?

Comment: As long as `col-*`s are wrapped in `<div class="row"` and you don't go over 12 columns per row, they'll fall in line no problem. The `container` is more for setting the overall width of the wrapper and doesn't affect the inner grid, per se.

Comment: I know this is a seprate sort of question, but what about this issue: https://jsfiddle.net/xcbLq2se/3/ where the text again overflows its container?

Comment: If text is too long for a container, you can control how it's displayed using the CSS `word-break` property. Lots of info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it should look like.

```
<div style="margin:15px;">
<br> 
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="well">
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <h4>Test Title</h4>
        <p>Some test text</p>
        <p>More text..</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      </div>
      <p>And Some Text Here<p>
      <p>And Some Text Here<p>
      <p>And Some Text Here<p>
      <p>And Some Text Here<p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```